# Mathematical definition of "partially sorted"

Tags: sorting, math, partial, insertion-sort

For example, insertion sort is described as an efficient algorithm for partially sorted arrays.  But how does one precisely define "partially sorted"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an array with few elements out of place. Without also specifying a percentage or other threshold there's no strict distinction between partially sorted and unsorted.

Formal definition from [*Algorithms*](https://books.google.se/books?id=idUdqdDXqnAC) by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne:

> More generally, we consider the concept of a *partially sorted array*, as follows: An *inversion* is a pair of entries that are out of order in the array. For instance, E X A M P L E has 11 inversions: E-A, X-A, X-M, X-P, X-L, X-E, M-L, M-E, P-L, P-E, and L-E. If the number of inversions in an array is less than a constant multiple of the array size, we say that the array is *partially sorted*.

The Wikipedia page for [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) formulates this as follows:

> [...] the array *A* will be partially sorted in the sense that each element is at most *K* positions away from its final, sorted position. [...]

Comment: So it doesn't actually have anything to do with what is described as a "partially ordered set" in mathematics?

Comment: No, I can't see any connection. In a partially ordered set, you may have neither `a < b` nor `b < a`, while in a list, all elements have a position.

Comment: I am a little confused about the definition found in 'Algortihms'. Say we have an ordered array of ints {1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6} with array length 6. If we reverse the order we get {6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} with 21 inversions. This is a constant multiple of 6 and is the worst case.. Am I misunderstanding the excerpt?

Comment: In addition, for the wikipedia definition, if the value of K = N-1 then this justifies any ordering..

Comment: That's right. With a sufficiently large value for *K*, partially sorted degenerates into completely unsorted.

Comment: Hey Fabian, I know this is late, but did you ever find out a solution to your small array issue. The one where you had 21 inversions in the worst case scenario, but it's still a constant multiple of 6? I don't know the rules of when it goes from linear to quadratic.